# abort called is showing in Hackerrank

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem of the array in which I have to do a left rotation of an array. wrote the code and submit successfully some test cases passed in some it showing abort called I don't know whats the problem. I googled it shows it's due to storage becomes full. what if I declare my temp array in heap. would it make any difference? forgive me for my indentation.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);
vector<string> split(const string &);

vector<int> rotateLeft(int d, vector<int> arr) {
    vector<int> temp(d);

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[d + i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr[arr.size() - d + i] = temp[i];
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string first_multiple_input_temp;
    getline(cin, first_multiple_input_temp);

    vector<string> first_multiple_input = split(rtrim(first_multiple_input_temp));

    int n = stoi(first_multiple_input[0]);

    int d = stoi(first_multiple_input[1]);

    string arr_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, arr_temp_temp);

    vector<string> arr_temp = split(rtrim(arr_temp_temp));

    vector<int> arr(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int arr_item = stoi(arr_temp[i]);

        arr[i] = arr_item;
    }

    vector<int> result = rotateLeft(d, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        fout << result[i];

        if (i != result.size() - 1) {
            fout << " ";
        }
    }

    fout << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

string ltrim(const string & str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(s.begin(), find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))));

    return s;
}

string rtrim(const string & str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(), s.end());

    return s;
}

vector<string> split(const string & str) {
    vector<string> tokens;

    string::size_type start = 0;
    string::size_type end = 0;

    while ((end = str.find(" ", start)) != string::npos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));

        start = end + 1;
    }

    tokens.push_back(str.substr(start));

    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: ***it showing abort called I don't know whats the problem.*** Time to figure out what test case causes the bug then use a debugger to understand what is happening.

Comment: You need to learn how to run these kind of programs locally on your own system. Otherwise you can't do something which such sites don't teach (and they don't really teach anything but bad code and bad habits), namely ***debugging***.

Comment: Could it be the case that sometimes `d > n` in some tests? In this case your program will crash with abort. Probably you have to make `d %= n;`. Can you also post a link to the original problem so that we see all task's details?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem

Comment: that's the question

Comment: Remember that the purpose of your question is to help readers perhaps years from now solve the same problem. What happens when the external site deletes the question?

Comment: @vikash -- If there are 10 elements, and I ask to rotate 1000 to the left, is it necessary to actually rotate 1000 times?  Think about a clock -- if the time is 1:00 PM and you add 100 hours, what would be the time?  Would you literally add 100, or is there a trick?

Comment: As Sean Parent would say: "That's a rotate."...So...did you try calling `std::rotate`, which by default left-rotates a range?

Comment: Sidenote: look into clang-format for a relatively easy solution for wonky indentation.

Comment: Take care with the first two lines. They make it really easy to have nigh-inscrutable bugs. Plus including the entire C++ Standard library murders the program's build times. You save a few seconds over typing in the correct headers, but you lose those gains after the second or third recompile takes about ten times as long as it otherwise would

Comment: Yes, basically the "real" C++ solution is  one or two lines -- `std::rotate`, and you compute the actual number of positions to rotate in a smart way.

Comment: You can cheat and not move any data at all. Print the "right" part of the vector and then print the "left" part of the vector. The variable `d` tells you where the right part starts. [This code passes all the test cases.](https://godbolt.org/z/a9ThGrPjh)

Comment: thanx, all of you guys I used the rotate function and it is literally 2 lines of code.

Comment: @vikash -- In general, the question you find on HackerRank have naive, slow solutions that always fail on timeout errors.  The questions are actually designed so that you can come up with a better solution in terms of efficiency.  You fell right into the trap of actually trying to rotate `n` times.  Even if you got your code to work, it would be doomed to fail due to timeout errors.  If you see a question that looks "easy", it usually isn't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie same thing happened actually my code passed the first 4 test cases then it failed all the test cases.

Comment: @vikash I just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66875663/941531), at the very end of my answer I provided shortest corrections to your algorithm to make it work (it will use `O(N)` time and `O(N)` extra memory)!

Comment: @Arty thanx man it finally passed all test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your 3 loops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[d + i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr[arr.size() - d + i] = temp[i];
    }
```

first loop will crash if `d > n`. It can be the case that your task may have d > n sometimes.

Second loop should crash always when d > 0, because `arr[d + i]` is out of bounds if `d + i >= arr.size()` which will always happen because loop is until `i < arr.size()`.

Third loop will also always crash because out of bounds. For example if `d == 1` and `i == arr.size() - 1` then you get `arr[arr.size() - 1 + arr.size() - 1]` which is out of bounds.

Also you have to watch if `d > n` in some tests, then you have to make `d %= n;`.

Also just a notice - inputs of most HackerRank problems can be read using just things like `int i = 0; std::cin >> i;` and loops. No need for strings operations like `stoi`/`ltrim`/`rtrim`/`split`. For example to read array of `n` numbers,
provided as one or several lines of input, you can do:

```
std::vector<int> nums;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;
    nums.push_back(i);
}
```

You can use just standard [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to rotate array left.

One interesting way to solve the problem in `O(N)` time and `O(1)` extra memory without `std::rotate` and `std::reverse` functions and without temporary storage is to reverse order of first `d` elements, then reverse order of last `n - d` elements, then reverse whole array. Of cause usually you just use `std` helpers, but sometimes you want to implement algorithms from scratch. I.e. something like following:

```
void reverse(int * begin, int * end) {
    --end;
    while (begin < end)
        std::swap(*begin++, *end--);
}
void rotate(int * begin, int * end, int d) {
    d %= (end - begin);
    reverse(begin, begin + d);
    reverse(begin + d, end);
    reverse(begin, end);
}
```

---

The shortest way to fix your algorithm (it takes `O(N)` time and `O(N)` extra memory) to make it work is:

```
vector<int> rotateLeft(int d, vector<int> arr) {
    d %= arr.size();
    vector<int> temp(d);

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - d; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[d + i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        arr[arr.size() - d + i] = temp[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```